# Why does my baked texture look different than my procedural texture?

Tags: shaders, texture-baking

Why does my baked texture looks slightly more pale and less metallic than the procedural texture?

[image]

Here is the procedural node network:

[image]
[image]

Here is the baked texture node network:

[image]

Here is my project file:
[Download Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3lzfh9jc6aquvkh2d42yo/Moon-House.008.blend?rlkey=fhjh4vw2mt6ytd0ra5ms4ay45&dl=0)

Comment: I haven't downloaded your 2 GB(!) file but in a first step, I would set the *Color Space* to *Non-Color* for the Normal, Roughness and Metallic nodes (last screenshot).

Comment: @Blunder That definitely got it closer! Now I just want to know why the baked texture looks more blurry than the procedural when I didn't touch any sampling, denoise, or image resolution settings since the previous render in the question above. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/razgsx5fsmrp67wms9p0p/Texture-Comparison-2.png?rlkey=8l7gy84l1wm7le8joxtibrkrk&dl=0

Comment: Every data except the base color should be set to `non-color`. So Specular should be non-color as well. For the bluryness, are your textures blurry, or the render? if it's the textures: check your resolution, and otherwise your rendering settings when baking. If it's the render: use OpenImageDenoise and more samples, because it really looks like what OptiX denoise does with very low sampling.